# Losing year dummy when running 'within' plm in R

Tags: r, missing-data, panel-data, plm

I'm working through question C3i in Wooldridge's Intro to Econometrics text and running the following code:

```
library(wooldridge)
library(plm)
jtrain.p <- pdata.frame(jtrain,index=c("fcode","year"))
fereg <- plm(hrsemp~d88+d89+grant+lag(grant)+log(employ),data=jtrain.p,model="within")
summary(fereg)
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Call:
plm(formula = hrsemp ~ d88 + d89 + grant + lag(grant) + log(employ), 
    data = jtrain.p, model = "within")

Unbalanced Panel: n = 135, T = 1-2, N = 261

Residuals:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-69.3970  -3.6473   0.0000   3.6473  69.3970 

Coefficients: (1 dropped because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
d88          -3.2060     2.8744 -1.1153    0.2669    
grant        38.2947     5.1475  7.4394 1.561e-11 ***
lag(grant)    9.2878     8.1609  1.1381    0.2573    
log(employ)  -1.4169     8.3407 -0.1699    0.8654    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    66446
Residual Sum of Squares: 31818
R-Squared:      0.52114
Adj. R-Squared: -0.020521
F-statistic: 33.193 on 4 and 122 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

Which differs from the answer I'm supposed to be getting, which is

```
hrsemp = -1.10 d88 + 4.09 d89 + 34.23 grant + .504 grant(t-1) - .176 log(employ)
                    
n  =  390,   N  =  135,   T  =  3.
```

Why am I losing one of my year dummies, and why do I only have 261 observations vs. the 390 in the text? Does it have something to do with the way my model is handling missing values?

Comment: The number of used observations and time periods per individual differ. Are you sure you estimated the model you wanted to with the same data set as the reference?

Comment: Also, something about the numbers from the "answer" seems fishy: if there are 135 observational units with 3 time periods each, we would see 405 (=135 * 3) observations used in model estimation, not 390.

Comment: @Helix123 I believe I did specify the model as instructed, using the same data set.

Regarding the number of observations used, the solution manual for this question notes that:

"135 firms are used in the FE estimation.  Because there are three years, we would have a total of 405 observations if each firm had data on all variables for all three years.  Instead, due to missing data, we can use only 390 observations in the FE estimation."

I suppose it's possible that the solution in the manual is incorrect, but I have found it to be very accurate through the previous 13 chapters.